# Error with definition of "(abstract) exception class" with function "what()"

Tags: c++, c++11

Given the following classes:

```
#include <iostream>

using std::ostream;

class MatrixException: public std::exception {
public:
    virtual ~MatrixException() {
    }

    virtual const char* what() throw ()const = 0; // error1 , error2
};

class BadDims: public MatrixException {
public:
    const char* what() throw ()const override {
        return "Bad dimensions";
    }
};
```

Can someone explain me why I get the following errors?

> expected ';' at end of member declaration
>
> expected unqualified-id before '=' tokenov

Comment: It should be `const throw ()`

Comment: By the way, the [`throw` specification](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/except_spec) has been deprecated, so you might be better off just removing it from the code (or replace it with [`noexcept`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/noexcept_spec) in this case)

Comment: ... or update it to be `noexcept`

Answer (score 0):

What @VTT and the other guys said, BUT, `std::exception::what` is declared `noexcept` so you shouldn't be promising / threatening to throw anything in the first place.

Therefore, the code should look like this (after a bit of tidying up)

```
#include <exception>

class MatrixException : public std::exception {
public:
    virtual ~MatrixException() { }

    virtual const char* what() const noexcept = 0;
};

class BadDims : public MatrixException {
public:
    const char* what() const noexcept override { return "Bad dimensions"; }
};
```

What mystifies me is why the OP's code compiles at all.  Perhaps someone older (if that is possible) and wiser (err, ditto) can explain that to me.

[Live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/pFOaKtbSNRQA3iEw).

Comment: `what` is `noexcept` in C++11, don't know why you are trying `noexcept(false)`.

Comment: @nm Well, the code's all there for you to look at and, innocent that I am, I expected it to work.  So why won't it compile?

Comment: You are using `noexcept(false)`. Why? This is wrong. The compiler tells you as much. You have a **looser throw specifier** than the function you are overriding. Not legal.

Comment: @nm OK, I understand now.  Have updated my post, thx.  I had that in there originally because the OP had declared _his_ override as `throw ()`, go figure (and, innocent that I am, it took a moment for the penny to drop that what we're actually talking about here is _`std::exception::what`_).